# Is google adsense putting other tracking systems on my website

Tags: wordpress, web, adsense

The only thing I have hooked up to my website that i am aware of is Google Adsense.  But my avast web browser plugin is telling me that the folowing Ad Tracking is present too:

- Doubleclick
- AdTech AOL
- Adobe AudienceManager

Could these be ad partners that google lets in or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes doubleclick is one of Googles ad delivery platforms.

If you are enrolled in adsense and have the option enabled they will serve with some of the and partner add platforms.

While its probably best to leave them as google will factor in for the best return you can disable via these instructions.

https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/191270?hl=en